# How to add Ok and cancel button in Theme.Holo.Dialog dialogue?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using dialogue activity .
so I am using this style for my Activity

```
    <style name="MyTheme.UserDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

How I can add ok and cancel button for this activity?

This is onCreate method for my Activity , I have extended PreferenceActivity .

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.filter_layout);
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("filter"));
}
```

This is how my Dialogue activity looks

[image: This is how my Dialogue activity looks]

**EDIT**
This is my layout file using PreferenceScreen as root element so I can't use button inside it ...

```
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="/movie/popular"
    android:entries="@array/filter_options_show"
    android:entryValues="@array/filter_options"
    android:key="filter"
    android:title="Filter" />
```

Comment: No clear idea what you want, You can add button in your `filter_layout.xml`

Comment: inflate custom layout in your dialog ...

Comment: i cant change add Button in my layout , i have edited my Question which provides the reason , thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.edit_profile_delete_account))
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.gen_Delete), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.gen_Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for onBackpress ok and cancel alert dialogue You can use below code ,
or you can use same code for alert dialogue anywhere according to your convenience.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    ServicesActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel, null)
            .show();
}
```